# How to create a vue app that has add to desktop feature enabled?

Tags: vue.js

I want to create a vue application in which I want the application to have the add to desktop option.
[image]

Like the one near the share option of youtube here. Any Idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome displays this for a [Progressive Web App](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/9658361), which will be detected via the presence of a [manifest.json file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest).